# What is the C# Node class?

Tags: c#, syntax

I'm (trying to) port the ChipmunkSharp C# physics library to Xojo. C# is not a language I am very familiar with.

The port is going OK but I came across a method with the following signature:

```
public static float bbTreeMergedArea2(Node node, float l, float b, float r, float t)
{
}
```

Is `Node` a native C# class or datatype as I can't find a definition for it in the physics library I'm trying to code?

Comment: In Visual Studio, put the cursor inside Node, hit F12 and see where it jumps to. There are some Node classes in the C# libraries (google for `c# node class`), but I don't think any of them would be useful for a Physics library.

Comment: Considering the name of your method with the word "tree" in it, I'm going to assume it's a Node in a "bbTree"

Comment: It depends on what namespace it's in.  If it's not in a `System` or `Microsoft` namespace then it;'s not part of the framework.

Comment: It's ChipmunkSharp class. Found here:
https://github.com/netonjm/ChipmunkSharp/blob/v7.0.0.Leaf/src/ChipmunkSharp/Common/cpBBTree.cs#L114

Comment: Thanks @DmitryRazumikhin. Not sure how I overlooked that. Been staring at the source files for 2 hrs!